# How to run my own application on a windows server 2003 machine so others can use it

Tags: windows, shortcuts, windows-server-2003

I've created a simple gui in python that grabs some xml from a db and emails it via mapi. I want the others on the support team to be able to use it.

I put the app on my windows 2003 server and put a shortcut on their desktops with a unc to the app on the server. I also use the /keep parameter on the target line in the shortcut properties; I'm assuming this keeps the connection open to the unc, I can't find any info on Google.

It works but it runs locally and most users mapi profiles are named differently. So the users are getting an annoying request to change the profile.

I could work around this issue but it would be easier for me to distribute my applications if I could get them running on the server via a shortcut.

I think I could use a mapped drive but I would prefer it if I didn't have to. We use numerous 3rd applications that run off a server using a shortcut but what baffles me is you can't see a them accessing the server if you do a 'net use' in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Server 2008R2 has a RemoteApp implementation that does exactly what you want to do. It uses the Terminal Services to pull that off.  Citrix uses a similar technology also called Application publishing.

Server 2003 does not have this feature though.